# Sum of precipitation per Timeframe in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe with a DateTime index. The data has an interval of 5 minutes. For every I have precipitation data from a hellmann [precipitation gauge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_gauge). The data I have does not show the actual precipitation in mm but the height of water in the gauge. So if I want to have hourly precipitation data I need to check for all rows in that hour if there is a delta between the current and the previous measurement. If so sum it up. But there is one more caveat, if the water in the gauge reaches 100 mm the gauge will be automatically emptied and the whole process starts from the beginning.

> if tprep - (tprep-1) > 0 take delta
>
> if tprep < (tprep-1)     take 100 - (tprep-1) + tprep
>
> if tprep = (tprep-1)     do nothing

Data:

```
8:00 78
8:05 78
8:10 82
8:15 82
8:20 82
8:25 90
8:30 91
8:35 91
8:40 98
8:45  3
8:50  3
8:55  5
```

This should make 27 mm precipitation in this hour. Of course it could jump several times over 100 in the timeframe, especially if the timeframe is larger. Does anyone know of an efficient way to get the sum of precipitation from such a dataset?

Comment: All conditions can be described as `delta = (100 + tprep - (tprep-1)) mod 100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your three conditions can be described as one `delta = (100 + tprep - (tprep-1)) mod 100`
or even as `delta = (tprep - (tprep-1)) mod 100`

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

data = """8:00 78
8:05 78
8:10 82
8:15 82
8:20 82
8:25 90
8:30 91
8:35 91
8:40 98
8:45 3
8:50 3
8:55 5"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=' ' , header=None)

df[1] = df[1].apply(int)
```

now I have DataFrame to work

```
df['diff'] = df[1].diff()
df['diff_modulo'] = df['diff'].mod(100)

print df
```

.

```
       0   1  diff  diff_modulo
0   8:00  78   NaN          NaN
1   8:05  78     0            0
2   8:10  82     4            4
3   8:15  82     0            0
4   8:20  82     0            0
5   8:25  90     8            8
6   8:30  91     1            1
7   8:35  91     0            0
8   8:40  98     7            7
9   8:45   3   -95            5
10  8:50   3     0            0
11  8:55   5     2            2
```

.

```
print df['diff_modulo'].sum()
```

.

```
27.0
```

Of course you can get it in one move

```
print df[1].diff().mod(100).sum()
```

Comment: Such a simple solution. Great thank you! One more question though. I have data of four weeks and sum precipitation currently on hourly base. This gives me lots of hours with 0 precipitation. The Problem is when I try to plot such a large dataframe as a bar chart pandas/matplotlib tries to also plot the 0 values and the plot is useless. have you an idea how to solve this? should I replace all 0 values with np.nan? Thanks

Comment: Regarding my last question replacing all 0 values with nan works. df['diff_modulo'][df['diff_modulo'] == 0] = np.nan of course I did this after resampling the dataframe